# Laravel on Plesk Routing Issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, plesk

I can't access my routes when I uploaded my site on Plesk. I get 404 error
I am using Laravel Version 4.2

I made the default directory to httpdocs/public/
Here's my .htaccess file in public folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$  [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Please help.

Comment: If you delete everything in httpdocs and then just make a directory called "public" with an index.html file in it, does it work when you access `http://www.yourdomain.com` without the `/public/` ?

Comment: I can see my front page right now. But not other routes like /login or /regiser.

Comment: If your homepage is working fine and you haven't changed anything in `.htaccess` then I would have guessed that mod_rewrite wasn't enabled. Is this a new server and do you have SSH access?

Comment: "httpdocs" should be your "public" because "httpdocs" is web root in Plesk

Comment: I am facing the same problem at plesk, I upload my laravel project at plesk server, My homepage is running fine but other pages showing 404,  My htaccess file is also seems to be fine, Could you please tell me how to resolved this issue.